# Mysql "Select mod(col1, 10) ... " generates bigint. How to make it to be int type

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have following code

```
String sql = "(select mod_col, 1 as count_col from ( " +
                    "select mod(col1, 10) as mod_col " +
                    "from table1 c " +
                    "where c.col2 = 1) temp " +
                    "group by mod_col, count_col ) as temp2";

DataFrame df = getDSEDataFrame(sql);
```

Note that the col1 is defined in mysql with type `int(11) NOT NULL`.

However, when I check the df, the mod_col has the correct value as a bigint. This cause an exception `java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer` for my following code

```
        List<Row> col1List = df.collectAsList();

        for (Row r : col1List) {
             Integer col1Val = r.getAs("mod_col");  // exception thrown here
        }
```

Is there any way in above sql that I can force it return an integer instead of a big integer?

Comment: This is just a guess but I'd assume that `int(11)` is interpreted as being too large for an `Integer` because the max int value as 10 digits (9 to be safe). I'm not sure what MySQL will do with that definition, i.e. whether `int(11)` will still technically be an int or not and Spark might not know as well and thus might want to err on the side of caution. Might explicitly casting to int in the query help?

Comment: How do you get value? If you calling `getObject` on `ResultSet` you may want to use `getInt` instead.

Comment: *when I check the df, the mod_col has the correct value as a bigint.* This is **NOT** MySQL issue. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=997202f419391b2e718e29375d3c1b1a). Make claims to your client software / programming language.

Comment: spark may guess the schema and could recognize the integer as bigint.

Comment: Hi guys, I updated the question with the code that throw exceptions. Please check. THanks.